# Strict aliasing of array vs std::array

Tags: c++, gcc, strict-aliasing

This problem depends on the GCC verion used. On 5.4.0, at least, the following code will fail:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

int main() {        
    uint8_t buf[12] = {0};
    std::array<uint8_t, 12> array{0};
    uint16_t data = 0x5511;

    *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&buf[1])) = data;
    *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&array[1])) = data;

    std::cout << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
}
```

During cmpilation with this error:

```
source_file.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
source_file.cpp:27:43: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
     *(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&buf[1])) = data;
```

I understand the concern with the aliasing. However, there are two questions:

1. Why does the next line compies fine? Why is the compiler OK with `std::array` and not with the regular C buffer?
2. This error doesn't occur in the newer compiler (above 7.2). Anyone knows why?

Comment: With regards to point #2, I "think" it has to do with the fact that the compiler is capable of infering that the operation cannot result in a conflict in this specific context, so while there is transient strict-aliasing violations, they are guaranteed to be impact-less.

Comment: @Frank I genuinely hope that is not the case because if I am writing *portable code* then I would want a *warning* even if there is no problem on this particular architecture. Especially if I set the `-Wstrict-aliasing` flag.

Comment: @Galik, strict aliasing has nothing to do with architecture, it's a property of the C++ abstract machine. So lack of aliasing assumptions are naturaly target independant.

Comment: What command line options do you use? I can't reproduce it [here](https://godbolt.org/g/JipRCN).

Comment: @xskxzr I managed to reproduce it like this: https://godbolt.org/g/4AjvEZ

Comment: Those `uint8_t`'s are technically `unsigned char`'s so maybe the compiler was updated to realize it isn't actually a aliasing violation because of the `char` exception.

Comment: Also this code would read a lot better if you got rid of the casting and just used `memcpy`.

Comment: @xskxzr: an option `-fstrict-aliasing` needs to be used.

@ZanLynx: sure, `uint8_t` are `char`. But why there is a difference between C array and `std::array`?